# Using time_to_sec() in laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, time

How can i use `time_to_sec()` in laravel eloquent ?

Here is my Query in sql :

```
select time_to_sec('00:02:00')
```

Is there any way to implement this in laravel eloquent ?

I have the value in the coloumn `charge` as `750` which means 750 $ for one hour

If i give 00:30:00 It should convert the value to seconds and do the same in the coloumn.

And the result should be `375`

It means for half hour the charge is 375

The mysql alternate is `select time_to_sec("00:30:00") / 3600`

I just want to know how to do this in laravel eloquent way.

Comment: Can you give us some more details please?

Comment: I have updated my question, please check it

Comment: Where would that `00:30:00` come from? And is your query longer or are you just using mysql to make a calculation?

Comment: I will update more clear in few seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DB::select()` if you'd like to run simple queries like that. `DB::select()` will return an array of stdClass objects containing the results of the query.

```
$result = DB::select("select time_to_sec('00:30:00') as seconds");
// print_r($result);
// Array
// (
//     [0] => stdClass Object
//         (
//             [seconds] => 1800
//         )
// )

$time = reset($result)->seconds;
```

### Edit

If you're trying to incorporate this into an Eloquent query, you can use the `selectRaw()` method:

```
$time = '00:30:00';
$model = OutSideCity::selectRaw("*, ((time_to_sec('".$time."') / 3600) * charge) as calculated_charge")->first();
print_r($model->calculated_charge);
```

Comment: But, i need to do this in eloquent , is it possible by doing it in model ?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably what you're looking for is the "raw" method. See: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: I don't need a query builder to use,, Atleast is there a way to do it using model ?